# How to debug a react native mobile app using chrome inspect

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The chrome inspect device doesnot list out the mobile application developed using react native.

I tried the react native chrome extensions but it didnt worked for me.

chrome://inspect/#devices

Is there any steps to that has to followed to inspect the react native apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should active `Remote JS Debugging` from `Developer Menu`. to access Developer menu:

You can access the developer menu by shaking your device or by selecting "Shake Gesture" inside the Hardware menu in the iOS Simulator. You can also use the ⌘D keyboard shortcut when your app is running in the iOS Simulator, or ⌘M when running in an Android emulator on Mac OS and Ctrl+M on Windows and Linux. Alternatively for Android, you can run the command adb shell input keyevent 82 to open the dev menu (82 being the Menu key code).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using React Native Debugger, which gives you a Chrome inspector but it is built specifically with features for React Native.

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger